# Using Gnustep to program in Objective-C in a Windows Environment

Tags: objective-c

I am using Windows and would like to start learning how to program in Objective-C.
I installed Gnustep and was unable to determine how to construct and build a project (equivalent) nor could I find an IDE (see [Gnustep getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060958/gnustep-getting-started) if you have a suggestion)

Are there any alternatives?
(I saw [Learning Objective-c without a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850920/learning-objective-c-without-a-mac) but i am fairly sure my question is different enough to warrant a separate question)

Comment: I did, and didn't find any that answered my specific problem.

Comment: @Mitch: if you know that it's a dupe, why don't you provide us with a link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535198/best-way-to-learn-objective-c

Comment: That really doesn't help me. I'm looking for a way to program with objective-c on windows, and i've tried gnustep and it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some bad news. There is no decent IDE for Objective-C available on Windows.And GNUStep is well so much anchored in the linux world that you probably won't be able using it without cygwin installed. However with CYGWIN and with the proper Environment variables set you can follow the GNUStep Makefile tutorial on getting your Objective-C running.

It's really a shame that such a wonderful languages like Objective-C lacks any useful IDE on anything  else but Macs....

Regards
Friedrich

Comment: Really? that's sad. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice answer to your question:

http://www.oreillynet.com/cs/user/view/cs_msg/22037

> Objective-C can be compiled by gcc, which means that you can use it pretty much wherever.
>
> However, as Retro says, the main strength of Objective-C in OS X is the frameworks. But
> Retro's a little off when he says that those are available only for OS X.

So it depends on whether you're learning Objective C for use on the mac or not.

Comment: I will be, but won't be able to program on it for a little while and want to learn the syntax first.

Comment: You might want to try this C and C++ IDE then, it seems to have GCC included. http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html 
.. I don't have experience of Objective C on Windows, so this is 2nd hand information. Search for Windows and GCC to find more. GCC is a compiler which builds executable code for many languages, including C, C++ and Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

install Bloodshed Dev-C++ (GCC front end) from www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html ...

install Objective-C DevPak from http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/packages/index.html ...

make a source file with .m extension and a main function and put it in a blank project...

use the tools menu to add -lobjc flag to linker...

F9...

viola!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a good text editor that supports Objective-C syntax highlighting (or language plugins) and GCC. 
Unfortunately, when you go down these esoteric platform combinations you have to make due with the simplest of tools.

Comment: sorry if i sound naive or something but what is gcc and where can i find it?

Comment: GCC stands for the GNU Compiler Collection and is a part of Cygwin: http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 0):

For syntax highlighting you can use notepad++ text editor.It has objective c language syntax support .But it is not a IDE.