# Can NetBeans be used to write Objective-C programs?

Tags: objective-c, netbeans

I want to learn Objective-C (solely the language itself, not Cocoa touch, etc...) on a windows machine. I saw the below link:

[Is it possible to execute Objective-C programs in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903869/is-it-possible-to-execute-objective-c-programs-in-windows)

but they all offer command-line tools and I'm looking for an IDE. I want to know whether is it possible to write Objective-C on NetBeans or not.

Comment: If you are dead set on using that Windows machine, likely the best environment would be to install Linux and use GCC or Clang + an IDE to write Objective-C code.   Trying to write ObjC in something optimized to Java is going to be miserable.   The best answer, of course, is to use Xcode on a Mac as it has the best support for indexing and the syntax.

Comment: Dear bbum I have a Mac at home but I want to learn by doing obj-c outside home and there I only have a win machine. Any win IDE you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on windows dev-cpp is the only real option. It usually already comes with all the reqired tools. However i strongly suggest to get the latest mingw and setup devcpp to use that one. I also have the source for a very basic runtime. So if you don't want to use the existing one feel free to ask.

-The basic setup works like this:
-install devcpp
-install mingw (make sure you install c,c++ and objective-c)
-add mingw compiler inside devcpp 
-enable syntax highlighting for *.m and *.mm files

now all you need to do is create a c or cpp project. Mingw will automatically compile *.m and *.mm files as objective-c code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For more info, you may visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078288/using-gnustep-to-program-in-objective-c-in-a-windows-environment/7563556#7563556